# Quantidade de campos - PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Montei algumas classes de crud em PDO e quase todas tem 4 ou 5 campos no DB, funcionaram corretamente.

Agora estou tentando criar um crud de 6 campos, mas não cria o registro no DB de jeito nenhum, reescrevi novamente a classe pensando ser algum erro de digitação, mas mesmo fazendo tudo novamente continua do mesmo jeito, sem cadastrar os dados no DB. O isset Post esta pegando os dados do form corretamente, a nomeação das variaveis estão corretas

Com 4 colunas no DB:

```
public function create($testA,$testB,$testC,$testD)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO ColunaUm(testA,testB,testC,testD) VALUES(:testA, :testB, :testC, :testD)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":testA",$testA);
            $stmt->bindparam(":testB",$testB);
            $stmt->bindparam(":testC",$testC);
            $stmt->bindparam(":testD",$testD);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Com 6 Colunas:

```
public function create($testA,$testB,$testC,$testD,$testE,$testF)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO ColunaDois(testA,testB,testC,testD,testE,testF) VALUES(:testA, :testB, :testC, :testD, :testE, :testF)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":testA",$testA);
        $stmt->bindparam(":testB",$testB);
        $stmt->bindparam(":testC",$testC);
        $stmt->bindparam(":testD",$testD);
        $stmt->bindparam(":testE",$testE);
        $stmt->bindparam(":testF",$testF);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Em PDO existe um tratamento diferenciado ao salvar dependendo da quantidade de campos?

Comment: Se não retorna nenhum erro. Tenta usar o toString() pra ver o que a SQL está retornando.

Comment: adicione a estrutura da tabela ColunaDois

Comment: @FelipeDuarte a tabela ColunaDois esta ok tbm, verifiquei os tipos de dados, os nomes e estão identicos

Comment: @cHida você tem um exemplo de como usar o `toString()`? seria: `public function __toString()    {  return $this->Db;    }` ?

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: @rray sem mensagem de erro

Comment: Faça  o seguinte e veja se aparece algum erro, mude: `$stmt->execute();` para `if(!$stmt->execute()){ print_r($stmt->errorInfo());}`. O código da pergunta parece correto imagino que esse não seja o código real (aquele com problema).

Comment: @rray retorna erro de que não foi cadastrado no DB por causa do isset que coloquei, se não cadastrar aparece a mensagem não foi cadastrado. Mas alerta de erro do PHP não esta aparecendo mesmo com o código que vc indicou

Comment: Não tem nenhum `isset()` no código da pergunta. Fica complicado responder em cima de um código diferente do real.

Comment: ok tirei o isset, do erro personalizado: esta retornando o seguinte erro: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'testF' ne peut �tre vide (null)`

Comment: testF é do tipo enum, no form estou passando o valor assim: `<input type="text" name="testF" class="form-control"  value="Disponivel" disabled>`

Comment: Pelo jeito veio vazio ou o valor não existe não tabela de origem. Tá tranquilo essa mensagem de erro em francês?

Comment: É melhor editar a pergunta e adicionar esses detalhes. pq não cria uma nova tabela ou trata essa lógico no PHP do que usar um enum?

Comment: É no minimo curioso, os outros testes com menos campos também trabalhei com enum da mesma forma, e não teve esse erro

Comment: esta aparecendo também o erro: `Notice: Undefined index: testF`

Comment: Não deve enviar seu valor pq o campo está como `disabled`

Comment: nossa kkk era isso mesmo, só o disabled que coisa eu nem pra prestar atenção nisso, pensando que era algo no código PHP. Obrigada resolveu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visto pelos comentários o problema era que seu insert enviou um nulo para um campo (`$testF`) `not null`. A causa está no form html onde o input tinha o atribui `disabled`. Logo a solução é remover esse atributo.

Mude:

```
<input type="text" name="testF" class="form-control" value="Disponivel" disabled>
```

Para:

```
<input type="text" name="testF" class="form-control" value="Disponivel" >
```